# Taylor expanding $F(a)=\int^a_{-a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+a^2}}dx$ around $a$ small

Tags: calculus, analysis

Is it possible to write a Taylor expansion for the expression
$F(a)=\int^a_{-a}    \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+a^2}}dx$ around $a$ small?

Comment: $\large {\rm F}\left(a\right) = {\rm sgn}\left(a\right){\rm F}\left(1\right)$ when $\large a \not= 0$.

Comment: Looks like integral doesn't depend on $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\frac1a\frac1{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xa\right)^2}}\implies$$

$$\int\limits_{-a}^a\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int\limits_{-a}^a\frac{d\left(\frac xa\right)}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xa\right)^2}}=\left.\arcsin\frac xa\right|_{-a}^a=\pi$$

So your function is a constant and thus its Taylor expansion is *very* boring...